# Add an additional property and value to a state object when transfering from one state to another. [Hooks]

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm building a e commerce meal ordering app. Trying to learn more advanced React.

I would like to add a quantity increment when the user adds more than one of the same item to order state.

I have some 'products' like this:

```
[
  {
   "description": "A rich blend, roasted for depth, smoothness and full body our coffee is harvested at the height of the season when the coffee cherry is at perfect ripeness, and sun dried in the fresh mountain air. ",
    "price": 4.5,
    "SKU": 1,
    "name": "Ethiopian"
  }
]
```

On click of a button the 'drink' is added to my `order` state.

`const [order, setOrder] = useState([]);`

With this function:

```
const addToOrder = product => {
    setOrder([...order, product]);
  };
```

And the state data looks like this once transferred.

```
[
  {
    description": "This coffee has been lovingly slow-roasted to develop flavours of smooth milk chocolate and gentle citrus for a soft, easy-going character. It's perfect for weekend relaxation.",
    "price": 4.5,
    "SKU": 3,
    "name": "Kenyan"
  }
]
```

Function being called

```
    <button onClick={() => addToOrder(product)}>Add to Order</button>
```

My problem is that I want to add a quantity value to this order state so the user can order several of the same 'coffee'. And each time the user add the coffee the quantity is incremented.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a reference checking by `SKU`.

`quantity` field is set to 1 for first order
else incremented on additional orders.

```
const addToOrder = product => {
  setOrder(prevOrders => (
    prevOrders.map(order => (
      order.SKU === product.SKU ?
      { ...order, quantity: order.quantity + 1 }
      : { ...product, quantity: 1 }
    ))
  ));
};
```

Other way of setting quantity is via `useState` if all products are fetched on init.

```
const [order, setOrder] = useState(() => (
  props.products.map(product => (
    { ...product, quantity: 1 }
  ))
);

const addToOrder = product => {
  setOrder(prevOrders => (
    prevOrders.map(order => (
      order.SKU === product.SKU ?
      { ...order, quantity: order.quantity + 1 }
      : order
    ))
  ));
};
```

Comment: I understand the idea behind your suggestion and have tried it. However, nothing is added to state. Here's the function being called     <button onClick={() => addToOrder(product)}>Add to Order</button>

Comment: Would it be because order.quantity doesn't exist yet?

Comment: @DGB see [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-bose-uckze?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Strange doesn't work on my app something must be preventing it. On render on my app. order is an empty array. On the first button click nothing is added to order. I will see if I can debug. Only difference between your example and my app that I notice is that state is empty array on first render. I will double check to see if I have missed something silly.

Comment: Doesn't work unless order state is hard coded and the button is specifically targeting items from hard coded state. My data is from an API and products are dynamic.

Comment: @DGB updated. For newly inserted product to set qty to 1

Comment: @DGB, other way of setting qty to 1 is by passing a function to `useState`. Just choose which one fits to your app.